# Diagonalizing symmetric real bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, symmetric-matrices

I am given the following symmetric matrix:

$$
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 & 1\\
        2 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 3 & -1 & 1\\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 4\\
        \end{pmatrix}\in M_4(\Bbb R)
$$
Let $f\in Bil(V), f(u,v)=u^tAv.$

I want to find a base $B \subset \Bbb R^4$ such that the matrix representing $f $ in respect to $B$ is diagonal.

I took $
        v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        0
        \end{pmatrix}
$ and found a vector space $V_2=\{v\in\Bbb R^4$| $f(v,v_1)=0\}$, and got $V_2 =sp\{ \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        0
        \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        0  \\
        1  \\
        0
        \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        1
        \end{pmatrix}\} =sp\{v_2,v_3,v_4\}$

Now, the matrix in repect to $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ looks like this:$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & -4 & 3 & -2\\
        0 & 3 & -1 & 1\\
        0 & -2 & 1 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I want to continue inductively, but I'm not sure how to procceed.

Comment: When you wrote $B\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, my guess is that you meant  $B\subset\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: You are right of course, edited.

Comment: User, since it has come up, as far as matrices, are you under the impression that you are solving $Q^{-1}A Q = E$ diagonal, or $P^T A P = D$ diagonal (which is what I think it should be).

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 1):

see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Also see jpegs at end of answer

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 3 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 3 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 19 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=====================================================

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that it can be done in a straightforward way. The entries of the main diagonal of the matrix of $f$ with respect to the new basis are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is $x^4-4 x^3-16 x^2+61 x-19$. It seems to be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: We don't change bases with matrices of bilinear forms as we do with matrices of linear transformations.  In particular, the new matrix will be [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) but not necessarily similar.

Comment: When we diagonalize the matrix of a bilinear form, the entries of the main diagonal pf the new matrix are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. Since, in this case, they are the roots of an irreducible quartic polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, there can be no simple answer to the problem.

Comment: Prof. Santos, especially on this site, the word Diagonalize is ambiguous. As with this example, the only thing that a student could be expected to make any sense of is finding an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^T A P = D$ is diagonal. The diagonal entries will agree with the eigenvalues as far as $\pm$ signs or zero, that is Sylvester's Law of Inertia. I asked for references about one method for this at  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  The method will give $P$ rational and $\det P = 1.$

Comment: @WillJagy I understand. Thank you for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0):

To put this another way: you've found an invertible matrix $P_1$ such that
$$
A = P_1^TBP_1
$$ 
(here, $P_1 = [v_1\;v_2\;v_3\;v_4]$). Now, consider the submatrix
$$
B_0 = \pmatrix{-4&3&-2\\3&-1&1\\-2&1&3}
$$
we can find a matrix $P_2$ such that $B_0 = P_2^TCP_2$, where 
$$
C = \pmatrix{\pm 1&0&0\\0&*&*\\0&*&*}
$$
All together, we have
$$
A = P_1^TBP_1 = P_1^T \pmatrix{1&0\\0&B_0} P_1 = 
P_1^T \pmatrix{1&0\\0&P_2^TCP_2} P_1
\\ = 
P_1^T\pmatrix{1&0\\0&P_2}^T \pmatrix{1&0 \\ 0& C}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&P_2}P_1
\\ = 
\left[\pmatrix{1&0\\0&P_2}P_1\right]^T \pmatrix{1 \\ & \pm 1\\ &&*&*\\&&*&*}\left[\pmatrix{1&0\\0&P_2}P_1\right]
$$
We can continue this pattern inductively.

Answer (score 0):

The method of repeated completing squares also leads, by nature, to rational entries in this case. However, that is not the end of the story, as the given form is $SL_4 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to a diagonal form. In brief,
$$  (w + 2x+z)^2 + (x-2y+z)^2 - (9x-9y+13z)^2 + 19 (2x-2y+3z)^2 = w^2 - y^2 + 4z^2 + 4wx +6xy +2wz +2yz  $$

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 4
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
Q =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 9 & -9 & 13 \\
0 & 2 & -2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and

$$
D =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The one-line formula above is just
$$  Q^T D Q = A  $$

As far as the order the question was asked, we take
$$
P = Q^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & -6 & 25 \\
0 & -1 & 4 & -17 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$
to get
$$  P^T A P = D.  $$ Indeed,
$$
P^T  =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
-6 & 4 & 1 & -2 \\
25 & -17 & -4 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$ and
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
-6 & 4 & 1 & -2 \\
25 & -17 & -4 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 4
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & -6 & 25 \\
0 & -1 & 4 & -17 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 9
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}
\right)
$$